# Duplicate request in web logic server 11g after every 5 mins

Tags: weblogic11g

We are facing an issue with long running threads in our web logic server 11g.

What actually happening is when we made a request in our application, if the thread associated with the request is taking more than 5 mins. Our weblogic server 11g is creating a new thread for the same request. that means we have 2 long running threads for the same request after 5 mins ( after 10 mins we will have 3 and so on ). this thing goes on repeat for every 5 mins and all the threads in the weblogic server get struck ed and finally server goes into "warning" status and application hangs out.

I suspected it as session replication issues but we are not using any clustered environment so I believe Session-replication will not be the reason for this strange behaviour of server.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Could be due to Idempotent setting of weblogic server plug-in is set to on and WLIOTimeoutSecs  is left at its default value of 300 seconds.

Comment: A bit of info about how we can change the setting would make the answer significantly more useful. Also, [is this related?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19816529)

Comment: Idempotent(default=ON) is Apache HTTP Server related setting, and is valid in the case where it is used in conjunction with Weblogic. It means that when WLIOTimeoutSecs have passed without any reply, the user request is invisibly sent to another cluster node (or something like it) that would be able to process it. It is set in httpd.conf of the OHS. See [reference here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/PLGWL/plugin_params.htm#CIHFFGEB), and [this nice article](https://pitss.com/us/2013/12/12/long-running-reports-crash-with-failure-of-server-apache-bridge-error-after-5-minutes/).

Comment: In our case (Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0), somehow, both settings were missing in httpd.conf (so I presume they took the default values) - but the duplicate requests were happening exactly every 2 minutes. I never found where this default 2 minutes was being set. After we changed WLIOTimeoutSecs to 1800 (e.g.) the problem was solved.